# PhoneGap or Appcelerator Implementation

Tags: mobile, titanium, appcelerator

This is more of an advice question rather than a specific question. I am developing an application for mobile devices.  Its basic functionality will be to open PDF files, Video files, and to open certain webpages. Would this be best implemented in PhoneGap or Appcelerator?

Comment: Here's a great article http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/05/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PhoneGap and Appcelerator Titanium are both very popular open-source JavaScript frameworks for packaging and deploying mobile applications. At Universal Mind, we have clients that leverage both and clearly both frameworks have countless successful implementations on numerous platforms. However, there are enough significant differences between the two products that it doesn’t really make that much sense to compare them directly. The fundamental difference is that PhoneGap is a web-based solution where Appcelerator Titanium is a pure JavaScript API that creates native code. At the core, they serve different functions for an organization.

**PhoneGap:**

- JavaScript API that provides access to Native Functions
- Supports HTML5/CSS3
- Supports Web Standards & Re-use Across Enterprise Apps
- Supports DOM based JavaScript Libraries/Frameworks
- Supports the most     platforms

**Appcelerator Titanium:**

- JavaScript API that provides access to Native Functions
- Compiles to Native Code
- Could provide better performance.

So as per my view i prefer **Phonegap**

Comment: you can check this article `http://www.universalmind.com/mindshare/entry/mobile-html5-phonegap-vs-appcelerator-titanium`

Answer (score 0):

I think a key difference implied is that PhoneGap uses HTML and CSS to render the user interface while Appcelerator renders platform specific native user interface components.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap have very small list of api that enables it to adapt itself to all(partially) platform, whereas appcelerator have larger api. That's is why they are emphasized on only two platform(completely). 
I think with this understanding i would prefer appcelerator for complex applications and phonegap for multiple platform.